# Python - creating objects from csv import list

Tags: python, class, csv, oop, object

was confused about how to make objects of people with different attributes using an import from a csv file.  The format of the imported file is simply a short list of names.  For now I wanted it just to be able to at least display the objects created as I can't seem to progress very far with what I'm doing   What I have below is all that I could think of to do, sorry if it's a stupid query! Thanks very much.

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 0
        self.wage = 0
        self.height = 0 

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

def importList():
    with open('peoplenamelist.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        maleList = list(reader)
        maleList = self.name
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point are you using your `person` class or iterating over the lines in the file. If you want to create a `person` for each name in the file you can try something like this

```
# Class names should start with a capital letter
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def importList():
    with open('peoplenamelist.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return [Person(name) for name in reader]
```

Then you could iterate over all the people like so

```
for person in importList():
    print person.name
```